# Named Range with CountA cannot complete the selection

Tags: excel, excel-formula, named-ranges

I have a named ranged defined as below for my dynamic selection but the the selected range always stop at halfway. I have total 2189 rows but selection stop at row 2063. Is there a limitation on CountA size? I have checked the data and it seems to be ok. Any ideas what is going on?

```
=OFFSET('Order No'!$A$1,2,0,COUNTA('Order No'!$A:$A)+6,COUNTA('Order No'!$3:$3)-0)
```

Comment: If you have blanks then COUNTA is not counting them. Better to use MATCH(1e99... for numbers or MATCH("zzz"... for text.

Answer (score 0):

The non-volatile INDEX can almost always replace the volatile OFFSET and it is recalculated only when something that affects its outcome changes; not when anything in the entire workbook changes.

If you have blanks then COUNTA is not counting them. Better to use MATCH(1e99... for numbers or MATCH("zzz"... for text.

```
'find the last number in a column
=match(1e99, A:A)
'find the last text in a column
=match("zzz", A:A)
'find the last number or text in a column
=max(iferror(match(1e99, A:A), 0), iferror(match("zzz":, A:A), 0))
```

You decided it wasn't important enough to provide sample data but I believe you need something like the following for your dynamic range.

```
='Order No'!$A$3:index('Order No'!$A:$XFD, match("zzz", 'Order No'!$A:$A), match("zzz", 'Order No'!$1:$1))
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to attach my sample data but don't know how to do that. Anyhow, your formula is works for me. Thanks a lot for your prompt response.